# bootstrap btn-group not needed inside of bootstrap form?

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Ok so... I was playing with buttons inside of a form, and I wanted to create a form with a question as a label and 3 radio buttons in front of the question (not below), and I wanted the buttons to be separeted from one another (not all together). and I wanted to be able to group the radio buttons inside of each row so that I'm able to choose one option from each row.

Something like this: (But without the actual "(x)", just the nice btn )

```
question:           (x)button           button           button

question:           button           (x)button           button
```

And so I wrote this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 2 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

  <title>
    test
  </title>

  <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~BOOTSTRAP~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style type="text/css">
    html 
{ 
  font-size: 62.5%; 
} 

body 
{ 
  font-size: 14px; font-size: 1.4rem;

}
  </style>
 </head>
<body>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="animal" class="control-label col-md-6">
                    Which of the following animals best describe you?
                  </label>
                  <!--no nned to add btn-group when inside a form-group-->
                  <div class="col-md-2" data-toggle="buttons"> 
                    <label class="btn btn-warning">
                      <div class="container-fluid" style="width: 7rem;">
                        <input type="radio" name="animal" id="jaguar">
                        Jaguar
                      </div>
                      </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-2" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                      <div class="container-fluid" style="width: 7rem;">
                        <input type="radio" name="animal" id="dolphin">
                        Dolphin
                      </div>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-2" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-danger">
                      <div class="container-fluid" style="width: 7rem">
                        <input type="radio" name="animal" id="ant">
                        Ant
                      </div>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <hr/>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="romantic" class="control-label col-md-6">
                    Which of the following escenarios best describe your ideal romatic getaway?
                  </label>
                  <div class="col-md-2" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-success">
                      <div class="container-fluid" style="width: 7rem;">
                        <input type="radio" name="romantic" id="forest">
                        Forest
                      </div>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-2" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-warning">
                      <div class="container-fluid" style="width: 7rem;">
                        <input type="radio" name="romantic" id="beach">
                        Beach
                      </div>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-2" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-info">
                      <div class="container-fluid" style="width: 7rem;">
                        <input type="radio" name="romantic" id="house">
                        House
                      </div>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- bootstrap scripts -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Which was everything I wanted. But...

The first thing I notice though was that the color darken when I cliked on the first choice from the first row but when I clicked on a button from the second row the first choice cleared again. That made me doubt, could it be that the radio buttons from the first row are not grouped and separeted from the second row??

And then while reviewing bootstrap info I notice I didn't used btn-group!!

... So I convinced myself that I could only choose one radio option from the 2 rows and I, definetly, didn't want that!!!!!

But oh I was so wrong!! When inside of a form you don't need btn-group (cause you've got form-group I reccon) and actually btn-group makes it more difficult to edit positions and sizes.

And to prove it here is some sample code, the aspect is very basic cause I'm not actually using btn display but it proves that without btn-group radial buttons will automatically group according to form-group:

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="animal" class="control-label col-md-6">
                    Which of the following animals best describe you?
                  </label>
                  <!--Look ma no btn-group anywhere!!!!-->
                  <div class="col-md-2" data-toggle="buttons"> 
                    <label class="btn btn-warning">
                      <div class="container-fluid" style="width: 7rem;">
                        <input type="radio" name="animal" id="jaguar">
                        Jaguar
                      </div>
                      </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-2" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                      <div class="container-fluid" style="width: 7rem;">
                        <input type="radio" name="animal" id="dolphin">
                        Dolphin
                      </div>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-2" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-danger">
                      <div class="container-fluid" style="width: 7rem">
                        <input type="radio" name="animal" id="ant">
                        Ant
                      </div>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <hr/>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="romantic" class="control-label col-md-6">
                    Which of the following escenarios best describe your ideal romatic getaway?
                  </label>
                  <div class="col-md-2" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-success">
                      <div class="container-fluid" style="width: 7rem;">
                        <input type="radio" name="romantic" id="forest">
                        Forest
                      </div>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-2" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-warning">
                      <div class="container-fluid" style="width: 7rem;">
                        <input type="radio" name="romantic" id="beach">
                        Beach
                      </div>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-2" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-info">
                      <div class="container-fluid" style="width: 7rem;">
                        <input type="radio" name="romantic" id="house">
                        House
                      </div>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
```

Further more if I tried to use btn-group, the display got all messed up. I played around with this configuration a lot and couldn't get the display I wanted. Here's a sample code using btn-group:

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="animal" class="control-label col-md-6">
                    Which of the following animals best describe you?
                  </label>
                  <!--no nned to add btn-group when inside a form-group-->
                  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                  <div class="col-md-2"> 
                    <label class="btn btn-warning">
                      <div class="container-fluid" style="width: 7rem;">
                        <input type="radio" name="animal" id="jaguar">
                        <span syle="width: 7rem;">Jaguar</span>
                      </div>
                      </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                      <div class="container-fluid" style="width: 7rem;">
                        <input type="radio" name="animal" id="dolphin">
                        Dolphin
                      </div>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label class="btn btn-danger">
                      <div class="container-fluid" style="width: 7rem">
                        <input type="radio" name="animal" id="ant">
                        Ant
                      </div>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <hr/>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="romantic" class="control-label col-md-6">
                    Which of the following escenarios best describe your ideal romatic getaway?
                  </label>
                  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                  <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label class="btn btn-success">
                      <div class="container-fluid" style="width: 7rem;">
                        <input type="radio" name="romantic" id="forest">
                        Forest
                      </div>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label class="btn btn-warning">
                      <div class="container-fluid" style="width: 7rem;">
                        <input type="radio" name="romantic" id="beach">
                        Beach
                      </div>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label class="btn btn-info">
                      <div class="container-fluid" style="width: 7rem;">
                        <input type="radio" name="romantic" id="house">
                        House
                      </div>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
```

So to conclude.... wtf??? I'm a noob and in no way I can claim that btn-group is useless inside of a form. As a matter of fact I'm probably wrong. But this display of things confuses me and I couldn't find a correct way of using btn-group AND!! having the display of the form as I wanted it.....

Is form-group enough to group radial buttons?

Is btn-group actually not helpfull inside of forms?

is there a better way to include btn inside of a form and respecting the wireframe display I described?

Pretty please if some has an answer i would appreciate any response

Comment: To be honest what I really need is validation... is my first form incorrect (the one that doesn't uses btn-group)?? is btn-group really needed when inside of a form-group??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work fine except that the width wasnt enough for the radio buttons. So i changed

```
<div class="col-md-2">
```

to

```
<div class="col-md-4">
```

NOTE : run the below snippet and view it in full screen mode

```css
html 
{ 
  font-size: 62.5%; 
} 

body 
{ 
  font-size: 14px; font-size: 1.4rem;

}

input[type=radio]{
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="animal" class="control-label col-md-6">
                    Which of the following animals best describe you?
                  </label>
                  <!--no nned to add btn-group when inside a form-group-->
                  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                  <div class="col-md-4"> 
                    <label class="btn btn-warning">
                      <div class="container-fluid" style="width: 7rem;">
                        <input type="radio" name="animal" id="jaguar">
                        <span syle="width: 7rem;">Jaguar</span>
                      </div>
                      </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                      <div class="container-fluid" style="width: 7rem;">
                        <input type="radio" name="animal" id="dolphin">
                        Dolphin
                      </div>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label class="btn btn-danger">
                      <div class="container-fluid" style="width: 7rem">
                        <input type="radio" name="animal" id="ant">
                        Ant
                      </div>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <hr/>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="romantic" class="control-label col-md-6">
                    Which of the following escenarios best describe your ideal romatic getaway?
                  </label>
                  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label class="btn btn-success">
                      <div class="container-fluid" style="width: 7rem;">
                        <input type="radio" name="romantic" id="forest">
                        Forest
                      </div>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label class="btn btn-warning">
                      <div class="container-fluid" style="width: 7rem;">
                        <input type="radio" name="romantic" id="beach">
                        Beach
                      </div>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label class="btn btn-info">
                      <div class="container-fluid" style="width: 7rem;">
                        <input type="radio" name="romantic" id="house">
                        House
                      </div>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
```

I'm thinking this is the kind of display you were going for.

Comment: This is more or less what I wanted yes, but I don't want the actual radial button (the little circle) to display inside of the btn.

Comment: Okay. If u need anything apart from this. Let me know

Comment: To be honest what I really need is validation... is my first form incorrect (the one that doesn't uses btn-group)?? is btn-group really needed when inside of a form-group??

Comment: okay i get what you're asking. In your scenario, yes you do need to use btn-group. And thats because each group of buttons (for each answer) are actually not really related to the other radio buttons, are they? So it would make sense to put the radio buttons for each question in a group of their own. Doing this would avoid some of the problems , you faced in the first part of your question. There can be one radio button of each group in focus.

Comment: you can read more about it [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups)

Comment: It makes sense and of course you're rigth! I just got really frustrated when my tests lead me to the same code you wrote on your snnipet... it's almost what I wanted but I didn't want to see the actual radial button... and so I wanted to just get rid of those annoying btn-group..... but you're right it wouldn't make sense. Thanks a lot for your answer. This is just what I needed :)

Comment: you want just the button and not the radio button?

Comment: I wanted the buttons to behave like radial buttons, to use for example in a form, but I didn't want the actual radial button (the little circle with the dot option)to be displayed inside of my button (btn)

Comment: check out my updated answer. you can hide the radio buttons so that they your buttons look like how you want them to. So now your buttons behave like radio buttons but look like regular button groups

Comment: Also I'd like to make a suggestion, next time if you make your question a bit shorter, you might get more responses :) Your question seems more complicated that it actually is.

Comment: You nailed it!! that's exactly what i wanted to display and couldn't!! 
input[type=radio]{   visibility:hidden; } was the answer... Thanks so much. I still have a lot to learn.

Comment: im glad i could help . If one of the answers above answered your question, the way this site works works, you'd "accept / upvote" the answer, more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Comment: I accepted the answer and I did vote up but since I have less than 15 of reputation my votes aren't taken into consideration jeje ;) 
But thanks again